# Effective UID is not root --> virtualbox --> ubuntu KDE

Tags: virtualbox

I updated VB yesterday, and today i get this error:

Effective UID is not root (euid=1000 egid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000) (rc=-10)Please try reinstalling VirtualBox.

where: SUPR3HardenedMain
what:  2

### VERR_PERMISSION_DENIED (-10) - Permission denied.

I can not run it and if i try to run it over sudo virualbox, i get fresh clean VB ( without any installed OS's ),which is really bed because i have 3 different OS on the VB with bunch of data in it.

I run synaptic but it looks like that everything is installed correctly.

Any input is very welcome !
E.

Answer (score 1):

Try to reinstall first.
If failed, check the user's rights of your VBox directory:
1 - root owns the dir
2 - some files have such uid set (-r-s--x--x), they are:
VirtualBox*
VBoxVolInfo*
VBoxSDL*
VBoxNetAdpCtl*
VBoxNetDHCP*
VBoxHeadless*

Comment: We had the same problem. It was the issue #1.